# In GCP, how can I run the cloud IDE on an existing VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Seems like it should be easy.  I have an existing Debian VM, and now I want to run the GCP Cloud Shell editor (https://shell.cloud.google.com/) on the machine, to get a browser based cloud ide.

Either launching the IDE from the VM or importing the VM into an IDE instance is OK with me.

Comment: Why don't you use Cloud Workstation?

Comment: Not familiar, will check it out...